# Can Javascript be used for back end?

Tags: javascript

I read [this article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/11/paypal-java-javascript) that says that PayPal may leave Java and go with JavaScript. I was amazed of this, does this mean that JavaScript can be used as a server side language like Python, PHP, etc? What I know about JavaScript is that it is a client side language.

Comment: Node.js. It's pretty awesome and worth learning about. It's becoming a hot topic in development these days

Comment: Check out http://nodejs.org/

Comment: [Serverside JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Server-side_JavaScript) does exist since 1994… - it's old hat :-)

Comment: I agree with @GabyakaG.Petrioli

Comment: you may also want to look a this [intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dO1zf4RXsTg)

Comment: It describes node's awesomeness despite that some people fight against it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Node.js

http://nodejs.org/

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily
>   building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an
>   event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and
>   efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run
>   across distributed devices.
>
> Current Version: v0.10.23